# Opening the same .NET Core solution on both Mac and Windows

Tags: .net, windows, macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've noticed differences between a .NET Core project created in Visual Studio 2015 and a .NET Core project created using `dotnet new` in Mac.

Considering that VS Code is obviously not the same than VS 2015, is it possible to work on the same .NET Core solution using both a Mac and a Windows machine or are the solutions/projects fundamentally different due to the .sln and .xproj needed in VS 2015?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work fine! I've successfully started .NET Core projects on Windows with Visual Studio 2015 and continued them on my Mac with Visual Studio Code 1.3+.

Visual Studio adds extra files like `.sln` and `.xproj`, but Visual Studio Code will happily ignore them. The only thing I had to do to get Visual Studio Code to recognize my solution was:

- Install the C# extension from [Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)
- Open the root solution folder in Visual Studio Code
- Open a code file somewhere in the project and check the lower-right status bar:

[image: status bar]

I first had to click a prompt in the status bar to enable C# support. Once I did that, it recognized all the projects in my solution.