# How do I export a C# project for Mac and Linux on my Windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cross-platform

I have created a console app using C# and .Net core version 5 on Visual Studio IDE. I understood how you can publish this app for the same OS. So now I can share my C# project as a .exe with all my friends. But all my friends don't have a windows. Since this is a console app, it said that I could share it with anyone having Linux/Mac. Also, I only have windows.
So the main question: How do I export my .cs project in such a way that I get files for Mac and Linux with just a windows machine? Also is it possible to do this without using non-Microsoft services since it poses security risks?

Comment: [mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792042/1997232), [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46843863/1997232). Not sure what "with just a windows machine" means, same as mentioned security risks (rant?).

Comment: *"share my C# project as a .exe with all my friends"* - sharing exe is publishing (or just running), but in title you ask to export project. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Sinatr I know how to "share my C# project as a .exe with all my friends" but I don't know how to share my C# project as .dmg or whatever is used for Linux. (I am not even sure if Mac uses a .dmg)

Comment: @Sinatr "with just a windows machine" means that I have a windows 10. I don't have a mac or a linux.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38640862/1997232) ? Or just [compile for linux on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41533592/1997232) ?

Comment: And how do you do this for MacOs?

Comment: @Sinatr how do u do this for Mac? Please help me. I am a very new developer in C#. If I do not get support I will not be able to move on. This will be then end of my C# programming and I just started!

Answer (score 0):

You might need MacOS (Cocoa) version for it.
I think is not included in MAUI.
Even I was wondering the same but the question answered it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).